# How can I make a Perl variable array get printed in another system like BDII

Tags: perl

I have written a Perl script that serves as a plugin in glite-CREAM middleware. The script is supposed to just print outputs and these outputs will be stored and published in the BDII database. The script prints all variables I want on the screen. One of them, called `@Store_MPICH`, is getting its value from another variable in a configuration file stored in a directory. It does not get published in the BDII database, even though when I run the script all outputs get printed including this variable `@Store_MPICH`.

The value of `@Store_MPICH` is printed `MPICH`. I guess the value of `@Store_MPICH` disappears along the way. I may need to use package and import/export it, I don't know really.

The ouput of my script is:

```
[root@helena plugin]# ./gokop
dn: GlueSubClusterUniqueID=helena.esc.rl.ac.uk,GlueClusterUniqueID=helena.esc.rl.ac.uk,mds-vo-name=resource,o=grid
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: MPICH
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE_1_0
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-ABAQUS
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-ABAQUS_6_9
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-CASTEP
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-CASTEPUTILS
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-CASTEPUTILS_5_5_1
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-CASTEP_5_5_1
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-DLPOLY2
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-DLPOLY2_2_16
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-DLPOLY2_2_20
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-DLPOLY3
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-DLPOLY3_3_06
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-DLPOLY3_3_10
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSIAN03
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSIAN03_E_01
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSIAN09
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSIAN09_A_02
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSIAN09_B_01
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSUTILS03
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSUTILS03_C_02
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSUTILS09
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-GAUSSUTILS09_A_02
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-IDL
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-IDL_7_0
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-NAMD
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-NAMD_2_6
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-NAMD_2_7b1
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-R
GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: NGS-UEE-R_2_6_0
```

The entire code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use IO::Dir;
use IPC::Open3;

my $Pub_prefix  = "NGS-UEE-";
my $Pub_version = "NGS-UEE_1_0";

$Siteinfo_file = "/etc/grid-security/siteinfo/site-info.def";
$Sw_env        = "CE_RUNTIMEENV";
$MPICH_tag     = "MPICH";
my $UEE_dir = "/usr/ngs";
exit unless -d $UEE_dir;

my @Default_tags = ();

my $Default_tags_file = "$UEE_dir" . "/default-tags";
if (-f $Default_tags_file) {
    @Default_tags = map {split /\s+/} (IO::File->new($Default_tags_file)->getlines);
}

$fqdn = $ENV{CE_HOSTNAME} || (qx{/bin/hostname --fqdn} =~ m{(\S+)})[0];

$dn = "GlueSubClusterUniqueID=$fqdn,GlueClusterUniqueID=$fqdn,mds-vo-name=resource,o=grid";
my @tags = sort grep {/^[A-Z0-9]+_?/} (IO::Dir->new($UEE_dir)->read);
@Site_entries = ();
@Store_MPICH  = ();
if (-f $Siteinfo_file) {
    @Site_entries = (IO::File->new($Siteinfo_file)->getlines);
}
foreach $x (@Site_entries) {
    if (index($x, "#") == 0) {next;}    # Comments should be skipped
    @line = split("=", $x);
    chomp(@line);
    if ($line[0] =~ /$Sw_env/i) {
        chomp $line[1];
        @values = split(" ", $line[1]);
        chomp(@values);
        foreach $y (@values) {
            if ($y =~ /$MPICH_tag/i) {
                @Store_MPICH = $y;
            }
        }
    }
}

print "dn: $dn\n";
print "GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: @{Store_MPICH}\n";
print "GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: ${Pub_version}\n";
for my $t (@Default_tags, @tags) {
    print "GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: ${Pub_prefix}$t\n";
}
print "\n";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@Store_MPICH is an array and I assume you like to use it as an array.

Try

```
push @Store_MPICH, $y;
```

and all matching values will be stored in @Store_MPICH.

But then

```
print "GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment: @{Store_MPICH}\n";
```

will fail. Change it into:

```
print "GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment:\n";
foreach my $value ( @Store_MPICH ) {
    print "  $value\n"; 
}
```

HTH 
dromedaryrider

Comment: Hi Thanks,
 
The code runs and gives the output of @Store_MPICH (that is MPICH in front of GlueHostApplicationSoftwareRunTimeEnvironment:) fine but again like the problem I had before, when I check the BDII database where it is supposed to appear, it wont be there. Could it be becuase on top of the script I declared @Store_MPICH =(); The value seems to disappear.